# REST API: URI and naming

Tags: rest, api

I'm designing a REST API that is gonna be exposed by one of my services. I've got a certain scenario that bugs me. Please advise!
I'll explain the case. the question will follow.

My service contains two modules "library" and "build" (this is original names, no need to understand what and why).
In the library, I have a resource called "procedure-step". For simplification, let's say, the procedure-step is a set of properties. To be more specific a set of property names. It's similar to the description of a type. It's important to say that in the domain of the application, the name is chosen like this (procedure-step). It's comfortable for them to call it like this.

Next...

In the build I also have a resource called "procedure-step". But here in this module, the resource is a part of another resource called "procedure". In the context of the procedure, the procedure-step has a slightly different model. Here, it's pairs - (property name, value). So it's like an instance of the type (procedure-step from the library). Here, the domain people, also like to call it procedure-step. They don't distinguish the context of it.

Now when it comes to defining the API.

I've got procedure-steps with two slightly different models. So in my API I can't just have a resource
/procedure-steps
because I have two different models.

Now question. The question is stupid, but anyway I have doubts.

Shall I:

1.
Have different names for these two resources? Like "procedure-step-template" (for my library) and "procedure-step" (for my build). Despite of the prefered names in the domain world.
In this case:
/api/v1/procedure-step-templates/{id} etc.
AND
/api/v1/procedure-steps/{id} etc.

OR

2.
Have the same name of the resources, but different URIs? 
Like
/api/v1/library/procedure-steps/{id} etc.
AND
/api/v1/build/procedure-steps/{id} etc.

So it's kind of same resource but different context.
The problem of this approach is that the names are the same, but returned models are different.
Also in client applications there will be confusion. They will want to implement a class "ProcedureStep" that will represent the resource. But it will be two different classes. Then the names will be different. And those names will not match the original resource name (because of the obvious reason).

Please advise! maybe other options?

Sorry for the long text.

Kind regards,
Alexander

Comment: By the sound of it, one of the models returns data, the other does something. In that case, just define different methods for the same route. For example: `GET /procedure-step/` and `POST /procedure-step/`. Better yet, qualify the URLs further: `/library/procedure-step/` and `/build/procedure-step/`.

Comment: BenM, thank you for your answer! Actually both return data. But the models are slightly different.

Comment: Yes, but does one *only* return data, while the other also performs some task?

Comment: No it does not. All the data is static. It's just a configuration. You can see it, you can update it. There are not any processes over this data. So both return some data that can be updated.